# String split in excel VBA gives type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Macro in excel VBA. I have a variable as follows:

```
debug.Print(Categories)
Tools & Home Improvement 
› 
Power & Hand Tools 
› 
Power Tool Parts & Accessories 
› 
Woodworking Project Plans & Kits 
› 
Woodworking Project Kits
```

I am trying to string split it as follows in the `Immediate` window but I get the error: `"Run Type Error 13, Type Mismatch"`

```
debug.Print(Split(Categories, ">"))
```

I am trying to extract only `Tools & Home Improvement` from `Categories` variable. Is there any other function that I can use for above.

Under `Locals` window, `Categories` is of type `Variant/String`

Edit:

`Split(Categories, ">")(0)` return entire
Tools & Home Improvement
›
Power & Hand Tools
›
Power Tool Parts & Accessories
›
Woodworking Project Plans & Kits
›
Woodworking Project Kits

It doesn't split the `Categories` variable.

Comment: `Split(Categories, ">")` returns an array, so you will have to print `Split(Categories, ">")(0)` to get the first item in the array.

Comment: **(a)** Are you sure about the separation character?  Is it maybe a different character that just looks like `>`? **(b)** It seems you have also newline characters in your string, you will need to replace them.

Comment: I copy pasted the debug.Print(Categories) as you see it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split returns an Array of Strings. However, Debug.Print cannot print an Array. You need to specify an index:

```
Debug.Print Split(Categories, ">")(0)
```

or

```
Dim tokens() As String, i As Integer
tokens = Split(Categories, ">")
For i = LBound(tokens) To UBound(tokens)
   Debug.Print i & ". substring: " & Trim(tokens(i))
Next i
```

Comment: Seems you have a different character as a separator. When I C&P the character from your output, it seems to be chr(155) while the less than-char is chr(62).

Comment: how do I figure what character that is?

Comment: With the `Asc`-function. I copied  the char from your the question, pasted it into the immediate window and typed `? Asc("›")`. That gave me `155`